# How to Get the value of variable passed to the Fast-Report (Version : 2022)

Tags: delphi, fastreport

//Adding a Variable "IsForDigitalSignature" to the Fast Report.
frReport.Variables.AddVariable('MyCategory','IsForDigitalSignature', True);

// Executing the report
frReport.PrepareReport(True);

//In the Report, i am changing the value of the variable to false in the script
// Set('IsForDigitalSignature',false);

//Getting the Value of the
frReport.Variables['IsForDigitalSignature'];
\ this will still return True even though I have set the variable to False

Can anyone tell me how to pass a variable and then get the modified value after the report is prepared?

Answer (score 0):

```
frReport.EngineOptions.DestroyForms:= False;
frReport.Variables.AddVariable('MyCategory','IsForDigitalSignature', True);
//In the Report, i am changing the value of the variable to false in the script 
// Set('IsForDigitalSignature',false);

//Getting the Value of the Variable
frReport.Variables['IsForDigitalSignature']; \\ This return now False as expected
```

I posted this with the Support Team of Fast-report. They replied with a solution.

Thank You